# Why not showing Android .apk file VersionName and VersionCode Right Click>Properties>Details

Tags: android, windows, apk

When I try to check my APK version number via Right Click>Properties>Details,
How can I show version code and version name of my APK?

[image: screenshot of Properties popup]

I want to check Version Number and Version Name from computer.

Comment: Windows has no support for decoding meta data of APK files. You have to use third party tools like https://github.com/skylot/jadx to view `AndroidManifest.xml` (which contains the `versionCode`) of your APK file(s).